# ERROR : Make sure JAVA_HOME is set, as well as paths to your JDK and JRE for java

Tags: java, cordova, intellij-idea

I started to use phonegap today. I cloned a project from github. While executing the project I got the error

```
"ERROR : Make sure JAVA_HOME is set, as well as paths to your JDK and JRE for java"..
```

Then I set JAVA_HOME to the jdk, by adding these two lines in the `bashrc` file

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

After setting the path I am still getting the same error?

Comment: What do you see for echo $JAVA_HOME; which java; echo $PATH  ?  Also can you clarify why have you added cordova and intellij tags?

Comment: Open `File > Project Structure`, look for a "project SDK" drop-down. This is probably not set.

Comment: Did you source your `bashrc` file after adding those? And then restart intellij?

Comment: After typing echo$JAVA_HOME, i am getting /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/

Comment: After doing that also i am getting same error

Comment: After doing source ~/.bashrc i am getting /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle as echo $JAVA_HOME. i restarted Intellij but still getting same error

Comment: did u restart from same shell? Maybe easier to reboot your computer to be 100% sure your environment changes picked up.

Comment: What happens if you type `javac` on the command line. Or `ls $JAVA_JOME` ? It's possible you are using a jvm that is incomplete, or not the correct one.